# Apache Kafka - Implementing a KTable and producing event using CloudEvent

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable, cloudevents

I have an implementation related to KTable and using CloudEvents to produce events, but for some unknown reasons, the produced event from KTable is not formatted based on CloudEvent. The implementation is as below:

```
    public void initKafkaStream() {
        StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        PojoCloudEventDataMapper<TicketEvent> ticketEventMapper = PojoCloudEventDataMapper.from(objectMapper, TicketEvent.class);
        KStream<String, CloudEvent> rawTicketStream = streamsBuilder.stream(rawTicketEvent, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), cloudEventSerde));

        rawTicketStream
                .mapValues(e -> convertToPojo(e, TicketEventMapper))
                .filter((k, v) -> v != null)
                .groupByKey()
                .aggregate(
                        AggregatedTicketEvent::new,
                        (key, val, agg) -> doAggregation(agg, val),
                        Materialized
                                .<String, AggregatedTicketEvent, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("aggregatedTicket")
                                .withValueSerde(aggregatedTicketEventSerde)
                                .withLoggingDisabled()
                )
                .mapValues(result -> {
                    try {
                        return CloudEventBuilder.v1()
                                .withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                                .withType("ticket_update")
                                .withSource(sourceTemplate.expand(result.getCurrent().getId()))
                                .withTime(result.getMeta().getOccurredAt())
                                .withData(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(result))
                                .withDataContentType("application/json")
                                .build();
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .toStream()
                .to(aggregatedTicketEvent, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), cloudEventSerde));

        streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(streamsConfig), streamsConfig);
        streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(ex -> StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD);

        streams.start();
    }
```

Has anyone had such an issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you checking the format?

Comment: Added the `CloudEventSerializer.class` for VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG in config and also serializing like this: ```this.cloudEventSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(
                new CloudEventSerializer(),
                new CloudEventDeserializer());```

Comment: I just solved the issue by adding configuration in the CloudEventDeserializer and CloudEventSerializer. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the configuration in props has been overwritten from Kafka streams in the serializer/deserializer, and by default sets the format to Encoding.BINARY. When the encoding is in Binary then the CloudEvents format is present only in the header instead of in the payload. To make sure that the serializers have the correct configuration I added them in the `CloudEventSerializer` and `CloudEventDeserializer`. In this case, the `Serdes.serdeFrom()` will be like the below:

```
Map<String, Object> ceSerializerConfigs = new HashMap<>();
        ceSerializerConfigs.put(ENCODING_CONFIG, Encoding.STRUCTURED);
        ceSerializerConfigs.put(EVENT_FORMAT_CONFIG, JsonFormat.CONTENT_TYPE);

CloudEventSerializer serializer = new CloudEventSerializer();
        serializer.configure(ceSerializerConfigs, false);

CloudEventDeserializer deserializer = new CloudEventDeserializer();
        deserializer.configure(ceSerializerConfigs, false);

this.cloudEventSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer);
```

In order to get cloud events format in JSON payload we have to use Encoding.STRUCTURED with JSON content type, this will do the magic and have the results in the payload.

Hope this will help someone who's struggling with this issue!

Best,

Comment: I am trying something similar with consuming cloudEvents using KafkaStreams but facing issues that I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695121/consuming-and-filtering-cloud-events-using-kafka-streams
Can you please take a look and see if you have similar issue or have any suggestions